# Adding, deleting, and editing input values dynamically with Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `UserLists` component where the user types into an input and adds the value onto the bottom of the screen.

The input value is added into the `whitelist` state. The state is then mapped and creates more inputs where the user can decide to delete said input or edit it.

I am having trouble deleting the inputs. I thought I could delete each input individually by splicing the state, but my implementation of the `deleteItem` deletes multiple inputs when any single one of them is clicked.

I also cannot edit any of the inputs because their `value` is set by my `addItem` function.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const UserLists = () => {
  const [whitelist, setWhiteList] = useState([]);
  const addItem = () => {
    let newValue = document.getElementById("whiteList").value;
    setWhiteList([...whitelist, newValue]);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(whitelist, "item changed");
  }, [whitelist]);

  const deleteItem = (index) => {
    let test = whitelist.splice(index, 1);
    setWhiteList(test);
    console.log("index:", index);
  };
  const editItem = () => {};
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>WhiteList</h2>
      <input id="whiteList" type="text" />
      <button onClick={addItem}>Add</button>
      {whitelist.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <input type="text" value={item} onChange={editItem} />
            <button onClick={() => deleteItem(index)}>Delete</button>
            <p>{index}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

How can I revise my code to successfully individually delete and edit inputs?
My [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/whitelist-63wwt?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Always check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) first. `Array#splice` changes the array *in place* and returns the *deleted items*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change your editItem and deleteItem functions in order to make your edit and delete functionality work properly. Here's a code sandbox link to the solution to your problem:

https://codesandbox.io/s/whitelist-forked-y51w8

Answer (score 1):

Don't do:

```
let test = whitelist.slice(index, 1);
setWhiteList(test);
```

Do this instead:

```
whitelist.splice(index, 1);
setWhiteList([...whitelist]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves a big part of the delete functionality, although I need to edit it to correctly delete repeated input values. Could you explain what I was doing wrong before?

Comment: `slice(index, 1)` doesn't make sense, please review the documentation of this method. For `index === 5` the return value will be `[]`, removing the whole whitelist array